# NodeJs Jenkins plug-in is not working with dockerfile agent

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use NodeJs plug-in on Jenkins. I follow NodeJs [document](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs) and it work fine with its example code which is using **agent any**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'NodeJs test') {
                    sh 'npm config ls'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I use dockerfile agent like the code below

```
pipeline {
    options {
        timeout(time:1,unit:'HOURS')
    }
    environment {
        docker_image_name = "myapp-test"
        HTTP_PROXY = "${params.HTTP_PROXY}"
        JENKINS_USER_ID = "${params.JENKINS_USER_ID}"
        JENKINS_GROUP_ID = "${params.JENKINS_GROUP_ID}"
    }
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            additionalBuildArgs '--tag myapp-test --build-arg "JENKINS_USER_ID=${JENKINS_USER_ID}" --build-arg "JENKINS_GROUP_ID=${JENKINS_GROUP_ID}" --build-arg "http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}" --build-arg "https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}"'
        filename 'Dockerfile'
        dir '.'
        label env.docker_image_name
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'NodeJs test') {
                    sh 'npm config ls'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will return **npm: command not found** error.
My guess is, It couldn't find the path of nodejs... I want to try to export PATH=$PATH:?? too but I also don't know the nodejs path.

How can I make the NodeJS plug-in work with dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS plugin won't inject itself into a docker. However you could make an `ARG` build argument in your dockerfile that takes the version of nodeJS to install. You will then need to get read of the `nodejs` step

Answer (score 0):

Thank you fredericrous for the answer. Unfortunately in my system, the dockerfile can't be modified. But from your information that

> NodeJS plugin won't inject itself into a docker.

I decide to run the NodeJS plugin in another agent instead of dockerfile(running multiple agents)
With the code below I manage to run it successfully.

```
pipeline {
    options {
        timeout(time:1,unit:'HOURS')
    }
    environment {
        docker_image_name = "myapp-test"
        HTTP_PROXY = "${params.HTTP_PROXY}"
        JENKINS_USER_ID = "${params.JENKINS_USER_ID}"
        JENKINS_GROUP_ID = "${params.JENKINS_GROUP_ID}"
    }
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            additionalBuildArgs '--tag myapp-test --build-arg "JENKINS_USER_ID=${JENKINS_USER_ID}" --build-arg "JENKINS_GROUP_ID=${JENKINS_GROUP_ID}" --build-arg "http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}" --build-arg "https_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}"'
        filename 'Dockerfile'
        dir '.'
        label env.docker_image_name
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
stage('Test'){
  node('master'){
  checkout scm
  try{
      nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'NodeJs test') {
          sh 'npm config ls'
      }
    }
    finally {
      sh 'echo done'
    }
  }
}
```